# Remove beginning of line before JSON starts

Tags: node.js, json

I have this method with a bug that will remove characters before JSON in a string, for example this line of logging output:

> Oct  2 21:37:03 ip-172-31-9-171 ubuntu: ["opstop"]

so I have this method to remove the text preceding the JSON:

```
class TrimJSON {
  sliceStr(o: string) {
    const ib = o.indexOf('["');
    const iz = o.indexOf('{"');
    if (ib > 0 || iz > 0) {
      let i = Math.min(ib, iz);
      console.log({i,iz,ib});
      o = o.slice(i);
    }
    return o;
  }
}
```

and so

```
 console.log(
   new TrimJSON()
    .sliceStr('Oct  2 21:37:03 ip-172-31-9-171 ubuntu: ["opstop"]')
 )
```

will yield: `']'`

since that is the last character. The reason is because of these values:

```
{ i: -1, iz: -1, ib: 40 }
```

is there some good way to mitigate this? My solution looks like this and it's pretty ugly:

```
  sliceStr(o: string) {
    const ib = o.indexOf('["');
    const iz = o.indexOf('{"');
    if (ib > 0 && ib >= iz) {
      o = o.slice(ib);
    }
    else if(iz > 0 && iz >= ib){
      o = o.slice(ib);
    }
    console.log('sliced json-stream string:', o);
    return o;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This assumes there is always a [" or {" in the string, you might want to add a condition for when there isn't or it will just return the last character as you've seen, but this will do it in a pretty concise way:

```
function trimJSON(log) {
  const i = log.indexOf('{"') > -1 ? log.indexOf('{"') : log.indexOf('["');
  return log.slice(i);
}
console.log(trimJSON('Oct  2 21:37:03 ip-172-31-9-171 ubuntu: ["opstop"]'));
// ["opstop"]
```

It's overly complicated to make a class just for that method.